# Alternatives for forEach when returning values looping through object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, object

I am looking to return from a `forEach`, but `forEach` do not allow `return` commands.

I have a function where I would like to pass an `object` and a `key`. I would like to loop through that object until a key matches the key within the param of the function, then return the value of that key.

I have built this:

```
const iterate = (o, k) => Object.keys(o).forEach((key) => {
  if (key === k) { console.log(o[key]); return o[key]; }
  if (typeof o[key] === 'object') { iterate(o[key], k); }
  return { "message": "error" };
});

(async () => {
  const obj = { x1: { y1: { z1: 'a1' } } }; const keys = 'y1';
  const data = await iterate(obj, keys);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
})();
```

However `data` at the bottom is undefined. I think the problem is `forEach` do not allow for `return` statements. Can someone recommend a better approach for this use case?

Comment: Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `.forEach()` to return items into a new array.

Comment: Use `some` for an early exit once the key is found.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried `.map()` to start with, again, it still returned undefined unless it was the parent element in the array.

Comment: @gorak I thought `.some()` only could return true/false, not the value of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - `forEach` does not support returning values (the returned values go nowhere).

A traditional `for` loop may be the easiest solution here, where we just want to return the first found value:

```
const iterate = (o, k) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(o);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    const key = keys[i];
    if (key === k) { // we found it!
      return { found: true, value: o[key] }; 
    }

    if (typeof o[key] === 'object') { // we haven't found it, but it could be in here:
      const deeperIterationResult = iterate(o[key], k);
      if (deeperIterationResult.found) {
        return deeperIterationResult;
      }
    }
  }

  // it was nowhere in o:
  return { found: false };
};

const iterateOrError = (o, k) => {
  const result = iterate(o, k);

  if (result.found) {
    return result.value;
  }

  return { "message": "error" };
};

(async () => {
  const obj = { x1: { y1: { z1: 'a1' } } }; const keys = 'y1';
  const data = await iterateOrError(obj, keys);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` for an early exit once the match found.

```js
const obj = { x1: { y1: { z1: 'a1' } } };

const getValue = (obj, key)=>{
 var result;
 (returnKey=obj=>{
    return Object.entries(obj)
      .some(([k,v])=> k==key && (result=v) ? true : 
       typeof  v=="object" && returnKey(v))
 })(obj);
 return result;
}
 

console.log(getValue(obj, 'y1'));
```

Comment: Is there any way to self contain the result within the `returnKey` function, so the function returns the value vs assigns the value to a value outside the scope of the function? If it can do that, I will mark this answer as the right one, as that's what I am looking for :)

Comment: @user3180997 Updated my answer. Take a look.